# ExportWeb from sites.asmx still pending (1)

Tags: powershell, web-services, export

I'm doing an ExportWeb method through powershell from sites.asmx in SharePoint 2013, and the exportweb job is still pending, even after days.

```
$uri = "http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/sites.asmx"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -NameSpace Sites -UseDefaultCredential
$exportjob = $service.ExportWeb("RootExportJob", 
                            "http://sharepoint/",                                 
                            "http://sharepoint/sitecollectiondocuments",
                             $false, $true, $true, 2014)
```

Then starts (I'm assuming) the export job, but it will constantly stay at pending.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked the iis logs?

Comment: how big is the site? are you exporting the site collection or subsite? did you see the Cab file?

Comment: Not sure what to look for in the logs (no errors), and the site should be relatively small (less than 500mb). I'm exporting the root site collection web (/), just the web no subwebs, which is why I went with the sites.asmx in the first place because it has a bool value called includesubwebs which I set to false.

Comment: The cab file is an empty file.