# Can ExportWeb (from sites.asmx) be performed in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, export, wsdl

I'm a global administrator, and I'm trying to run the `ExportWeb` method from https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/sites.asmx in SharePoint Online. When I run the following script, I get the response `3`, and I learned from the comments of [this](https://passionatetechie.blogspot.com/2012/05/export-import-sharepoint-site-using-web.html) article that `3` means an argument is invalid. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? The only thing I can think of is that this does not work in SharePoint Online.

***Prerequisite:*** I want to export https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA to the document library at https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteB/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. Both locations already exist, both sites are modern team sites, and I have confirmed that there is enough space for the operation. I have tried the script both with the ending `/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and without it.

***PowerShell I Ran***:

```
$cred=Get-Credential
$svc=New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Sites.asmx?WSDL" -Credential $cred
$svc.ExportWeb("siteExportJob", "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA", "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteB/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx", $true, $true, $false, 1024)
```

I looked at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101451/exportweb-from-sites-asmx-still-pending-1) question, but it never received an answer, and my problem is that an argument is invalid.

Edit: Is it possible that this is caused by the export location needing to be on my computer? This would be problematic because I am using a web service proxy.

Comment: There is no PowerShell command available for backup and restore in SharePoint Online. [Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10/backup-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/fd807be3-8329-4946-9e92-8b54e2d2ba50#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20PowerShell%20command,and%20restore%20in%20SharePoint%20Online.&text=Disclaimer%3A%20Microsoft%20provides%20no%20assurances,any%20support%20related%20to%20technology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you should store the backup on your local computer instead of a document library. You'd need to use C# for that, and I don't think you can get the right DLL for SharePoint Online.